# How to create N nested for loops in python

Tags: python

I would like to make N nested for loops in python. E.g.:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    block1=i
    for j in range(1+i,100-i):
        block2=j
        for k in range(1+j,100-j):

        . . . 
            nth for loop:
                for nth in range(1+(prior for loop value),100-(prior for loop value))
```

In this specific instance, what I am trying to do is to check all possible combinations of values for a group of n variables, given that the variables be integers between 1 and 100. For example, if n is 3, then I want to check all possible combinations such as:
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
. . .
97,98,99.

Similarly if n is 4, I'd want to check:
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,6
. . .
96,97,98,99

(I don't need to check multiple instances of the same number. E.g. if n=3, 25,25,25 would be a wasted calculation.)

I would then perform some calculation using these n variables.

Thank you and please let me know if I could provide further clarification.

Comment: Without knowing more about your problem, recursion seems like a possible solution.

Comment: Seems like what you really want is to loop over all sorted n-tuples with unique numbers between 1 and 99. Better make it a single for loop.

Comment: provide more info about your problem. What you want to achieve?

Comment: If you tell us what the last nested loop is supposed to _do_, maybe we could suggest an alternative algorithm that would actually work.

Comment: This is also known as the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` module has tools for iteration. Normally for nested `for` loops you think of `itertools.product`  but as @RemcoGerlich points out, it seems like you just want to generate increasing n-tuples in lexicographic order.  `itertools.combinations` is made to order for this.

> itertools.combinations(iterable, r) Return r length subsequences of
>   elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their
>   value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat
>   values in each combination.

Try `itertools.combinations(range(1,100), n)`